# Pasar datos de una blade al JS

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Estoy usando Laravel y tengo una blade con la variable:

```
{{$project->slug}}
```

En la blade también tengo un boton con el que quiero abrir una ventana nueva, pero como tengo diferentes proyectos tiene que ser 'dinamico'.

El codigo del boton es el siguiente:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm on buttonpreview" target="_blank" id="urlproyecto">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>Ver Proyecto
</button>
```

El codigo JS es el siguiente:

```
$("#urlproyecto").click(function(){
    window.open('http://'+window.location.hostname+'/es/works/')
})
```

En el codigo JS debería de añadir, al final de la URL la variable `{{$project->slug}}`

¿Cual seria la manera mas eficiente de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Puedes crear una variable en javascript y asignarle la traida desde la controladora   
$("#urlproyecto").click(function(){
    var slug = '{{ $project->slug }}'; //En caso de que slug no sea una cadena pones = {{ project->slug }} sin las '
    window.open('http://'+window.location.hostname+'/es/works/'+slug);
});

//O puedes incrustarla exactamente donde necesites
$("#urlproyecto").click(function(){
    window.open('http://'+window.location.hostname+'/es/works/{{ $project->slug }}');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que he hecho es obtener el valor de un input en el JS.

```
$("#urlproyecto").click(function(){
    var valorSlug = document.getElementById("slug").value;
    window.open('http://'+window.location.hostname+'/es/works/'+valorSlug)
})
```